# Need a logic for my android game

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Hi I am new to Unity game engine and I am creating a 3d shooting game. In the level 1 I want to shoot 5 enemies in certain amount of time let's say 30sec. After completing level 1, I want to go to level 2 where my total enemies are 10 and want to kill it in 60sec and if fail there will be game over. I wrote some script for it, it works a little bit but it is not perfect because after starting level 2 the game become slow and after game over the level 2 restart again but not with the default value of 10 enemies, rather it starts from the no. which reaches at the time of game over. needs some idea and good logic and script for my game. here is my code.

```
 public class Status : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static int TotalZombies=5;
    public static float timeLeft=25.0f; 

 // destry this game object.
            Destroy (this.gameObject);
            TotalZombies--;
            }
```

and here is my other script where I am handling my levels and time etc.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Generate : MonoBehaviour {
    public GUIText Zombiesobject;
    public string zombiesscore;
    public GUIText countdown;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        zombiesscore = "Zombies Left: " + Status.TotalZombies.ToString ();
        Zombiesobject.text = (zombiesscore);

        Status.timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (Status.timeLeft <= 0.0f && Status.TotalZombies > 0) 
        {
            countdown.text = "Game Over";
            Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
} 
        else if (Status.timeLeft <= 10.0f && Status.TotalZombies > 0) 
        {
            countdown.text = "Time left = " + (int)Status.timeLeft + " seconds" + "  \n  You are running out of time!";
        } 
        else if (Status.timeLeft > 0.0f && Status.TotalZombies <= 0) {
                countdown.text = "You win!";
                Application.LoadLevel("level 2");
                Status.TotalZombies=10;
                Status.timeLeft=59.0f;
        }
        else
        {
            countdown.text = "Time left = " + (int)Status.timeLeft + " seconds";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: also it hangs after game over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you use `static` variables. `static`'s are exactly like global variables. The only difference is that you need to access those through a Class name.

So what does that exactly mean? When you load your game, and when the class itself gets loaded the static variables are created and initialised. In your case it is `TotalZombies` set to `5` and `timeLeft` to `25f`.

But those variables persist and never gets re-initialized as long as your game runs. Even if you do a `Application.LoadLevel` these variables and their values persists.

That means if you change those variables, and reload your level `TotalZombies` and `timeLeft` still have their last values.

Because of this i encourage to never use `static` variables. They easily introduce hard to spot bugs. Let's for assume a simple fix to your code.

You additionally add an initialization to your `Start()` Method. For example in your `Status` class you add.

```
void Start() {
    TotalZombies = 5;
    timeLeft     = 25.0f;
}
```

In your case it could solve the problem completely, but you also could say this is just by accident or luck.

In Unity there don't exists an order in which `Start()` is called. It could for example still happen that the `Start` method in your `Generate` class is called first on loading a Scene. If you used `Status.TotalZombies` or `Status.timeleft` in `Start` to initialize something in `Generate` you still have your bug that your initializiation is wrong because it uses the variables from the previous run. The problem is Unity could sometimes first execute `Status.Start()` before `Generate.Start()` sometimes the other way around. That would lead to a bug that just `sometimes` occur and is extremely hard to debug.

If you knew the above you could also put your initialization in the `Awake` method. Because `Awake` methods will be called before any `Start` method. So this will be a better fix.

But there exists other problems. For example lets look into your `Generate.Update()` method. You for example directly do a `Status.timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;` in your `Update` method. But when you for example have multiple `GameObjects` in your game that has the `Generate` Component it means `timeLeft` will be decreased multiple times in a single frame. If you have two `Generate` Components it means your time will run out twice as fast.

So even putting an initialization into `Start` or `Awake` can fix some bugs, but you still have different problems with `static`s

That is a reason why i encourage not to use `static` at all. So how do you fix also this problem? Instead of having static you should create Attributes of a class. And on top of that you should make all your attributes only set-able only from your own class. That also has an impact on other code. For example you could not reduce the `timeLeft` attribute anymore from `Generate`. That sounds like a disadvantage, but it forces to think you about how to change `timeLeft` correctly. In your case you do not really want that any class from everywhere can change `timeLeft`. It is a time that should be constantly reduced and it is just an error to reduce it multiple time. The result of that is. Your `Status` class should only change the `timeLeft` in the `Update`. The same goes for `TotalZombies`. It would be better to just have a method like `IncrementTotalZombies` and `DecrementTotalZombies` instead of doing `Status.TotalZombies++` and so on. For example your `Status` class should now look like

```
public class Status : MonoBehaviour {
    public int   TotalZombies { get; private set; }
    public float TimeLeft     { get; private set; }

    void Awake() {
        this.TotalZombies = 5;
        this.TimeLeft     = 25f;
    }

    void Update() {
        this.TimeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    public void IncreaseTotalZombies() {
        this.TotalZombies++;
    }

    public void DecreaseTotalZombies() {
        if ( this.TotalZombies <= 0 ) {
            throw new ApplicationException("Cannot decrease TotalZombies. Already 0. Possible Bug in your code.");
        }
        this.TotalZombies--;
    }
}
```

Now the `IncreaseTotalZombies` or `DecreaseTotalZombies` sounds like overhead, but you can do a lot of extra checking here. For example check if the counter never gets smaller than zero. Because when it does, you have a bug somewhere in your code. For example Increasing your TotalZombies accidentally by two, or somewhere else decreasing it by two and so on. You also could implement a `MaxTotalZombies` attribute that ensures that you never get more Zombies as defined. And if that happens it will throw an Exception pointing it to your code directly where it happened.

It is also easier to identify bugs. Because Increasing it twice in a row looks wrong.

```
status.IncreaTotalZombies();
status.IncreaTotalZombies();
```

where following code can just look right

```
Status.TotalZombies += 2;
```

But if you do the above changes you will see your current `Status.TotalZombies` will not work anymore. You also have to change how to get an instance of your `Status` class. For this lets assume you create a GameObject in Unity named `Status`. Then in your `Generate` class you should add the following.

```
private Status status;
void Awake() {
    this.status = GameObject.Find("Status").GetComponent<Status>();
}
```

Now you can replace the `Status.TotalZombies++` and so on with `status.IncreaseTotalZombies()`. If you just want to get the values, you still just can write `status.TimeLeft` but setting the value `status.TimeLeft -= Time.deltaTime` will now throw an error. And you don't need to set it anymore because that is a behaviour that the `Status` class already handle in his `Update` Method.

Now additonally in your `Generate` class you had code like this.

```
Application.LoadLevel("level 2");
Status.TotalZombies=10;
Status.timeLeft=59.0f;
```

This didn't work as expected. Because when you call `Application.LoadLevel()` your new Scene gets called and the lines behind it was was never called. You could fix this be changing the order.

```
Status.TotalZombies=10;
Status.timeLeft=59.0f;
Application.LoadLevel("level 2");
```

Because your Status where `static` the value persists through loading. But the whole approach is still not really good. The Problem is you hardcode values in your code. And it seems you want different amount of Zombies and Time for every level. If you want that you can just add Attributes to your `Status` class that initialize your variables, And those variables are set-able through your Unity IDE. For example add the following attributes to your `Status` class.

```
public int   _StartZombies = 5;
public float _StartTime    = 25f;
```

If you add this to your `Status` class now in your IDE two TextBoxes will appear named `Start Zombies` and `Start Time`. In this boxes you can now enter how many Zombies or how much Start time your Level should have. The default values are `5` and `25` for those values. But those values didn't get applied on loading your level. To also apply those values when your level gets loaded change your `Awake` method to.

```
void Awake() {
    this.TotalZombies = this._StartZombies;
    this.TimeLeft     = this._StartTime;
}
```

Now `this.TotalZombies` and `this.TimeLeft` always get the values that you have configured in your IDE. The only thing you now need to do is to write.

```
Application.LoadLevel("SomeLevel");
```

And you just can configure the amount of Zombies and time through your IDE! It also means you now have reusable Components. And you configure things where it belongs!

---

You also described that you want different conditions to loading a new Level. For example if a user is able to kill all the Zombies in a specific amount of time he directly jumps to Level 3 instead of Level 2 and so on. So how can you add this, without creating a lot of special classes?

At first you need a class on its own that just hold data. In your case you want a specific time and a definition which level gets loaded. So you could write something like this.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class LoadLevelData {
    public float  TimeLeft;
    public string LoadLevel;
}
```

But in my opinion that logic belongs to the `Status` class, so what you now do is add the following to this class.

```
public LoadLevelData[] _NextLevels;
```

As soon as you add that to your code. In the Unity IDE you will see "Next Levels" with a "Cursor". You now can expand this cursor and a `Size` field will appear. You now can for example write 2 into it and it gives you `Element 0` and `Element 1`. So Unity gives you the ability to create an Array of objects and you can create as many entries as you want from the IDE with any values that you want!

Now you could write a `LoadNextLevel` Method in such a way.

```
public void LoadNextLevel() {
    foreach ( var level in this._NextLevels ) {
        if ( level.TimeLeft > this.TimeLeft ) {
            Application.LoadLevel(level.LoadLevel);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can configure in the Unity IDE

```
Element 0:
    Time Left  -> 20
    Next Level -> "Level 3"

Element 1:
    Time Left -> 10
    Next Level -> "Level 2"
```

You only need to call `status.LoadNextLevel()` when your game finished. And you can configure everything from the IDE. Also note. The order in which you fill your _NextLevel Array is important. In this case "Time Left" -> 20 must be before "10".

Comment: thanks...is there any way where in Generate class I control all the game levels and my enemies numbers and time? like before going to level 3 I want to change my enemies to 15 and time to 15.0f?

Comment: @user I added it at the end. Best way is if you don't use static and initliaze them from other values, like `_StartZombies`. In this way you can configure the time and Zombies from the Unity IDE instead of setting it through code. Setting it through code with initialization and still using static is not a good way. Because on every load your `Awake` or `Start` reset it to default values. It will only work if you set the statics before `LoadLevel` and never initialize the values with `Start` or `Awake`.

Comment: is it a good idea to use different generate classes for different levels? like generate level 1 , generate level 2 where I set my enemy and time individually?

Comment: @user When you do exactly the same in your Generate classes only with different values like Zombies and time it is not a good idea. Because you have a lot of duplicated code. Search for "DRY-principle". If just the values change just make them configurable through the Unity IDE! So you don't need to write a Generate class for every level. I mean, it saves time, right? But if you follow all the instruction i gave you, you will exactly end with a single `Status` and `Generate` class that is configurable in such a way. Without that you need multiple `Generate1`, `Generate2` classes and so on.

Comment: but I cant figure it out how can I go from level 2 with values zombies 15 and timeleft 40sec? As I have set the different time conditions like if (timeLeft > 0 && Totalzombies <= 0), then it will load the level 2 rather than my new level 3?

Comment: If you create the classes like i explained your have a `Status` GameObject in every Level. When you open your Level 2 in Unity you can just click on the GameObject that holds the `Status` component and you can configure the amount of Zombies and time for this level. You can do that exactly the same with all of your Levels. In such a way you don't need to set the correct amount of Zombies and time anymore for every level. You just do `Application.LoadLevel("Level 2")` and in your Level 2 Scene itself it is configured how many Zombies/Time it have.

Comment: @user I added some extra code that does what you described.